# Get what exists in one DataTable but not another using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have two `DataTable`s. I want to get what exists in the first one but does not exist in the second one. I would like the results in another `DataTable`. I would like to use LINQ.

- The First datatable:

---

```
DataTable dt1 = cc1roleDAL.GetAll(x, 0);
```

- The second datatable:

---

```
DataTable dt2 = cc1roleDAL.GetSpecific(x);
```

> Note: the column names I return from the the two datatables:

1. `crs_name`
2. `name`

Comment: Where do the DataTables come from? If the data's in a SQL Server, SQLMetal can generate your DBML so you work in Entities and the LINQ becomes easier. (Especially if your foreign keys are correct).

Comment: hmmm, sorry it's Informix database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do the trick for you:

```
var rowsOnlyInDt1 = dt1.AsEnumerable().Where(r => !dt2.AsEnumerable()
                    //make sure there aren't any matching names in dt2
                    .Any(r2 => r["crs_name"].Trim().ToLower() == r2["crs_name"].Trim().ToLower() && r["name"].Trim().ToLower() == r2["name"].Trim().ToLower()));
```

or if you prefer query syntax:

```
var rowsOnlyInDt1 = from r in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                    //make sure there aren't any matching names in dt2
                    where !dt2.AsEnumerable().Any(r2 => r["crs_name"].Trim().ToLower() == r2["crs_name"].Trim().ToLower() && r["name"].Trim().ToLower() == r2["name"].Trim().ToLower())
                    select r;
```

You can then put the results into a DataTable by using the [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx) function:

```
DataTable result = rowsOnlyInDt1.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: the comparsion should be among `a.crs_name and b.crs_name` `a.name and b.name`.. Not between `crs_name and name`.

Comment: i mean there are two fields with the same name in the two datatables:
`dt1:crs_name,name`  AND  `dt2:crs_name,name`.

Comment: i wanna to compare the first field with the first and the second with the second.

Comment: Aha! Ok I understand now.  Give me a sec and I'll sort it

Comment: I've updated my answer, is that more along the lines of what you want?

Comment: Thanks, but when i trace the code :rowsOnlyInDt1 is two records the same as `dt1`. although:dt2 has one record where  `crs_name in the dt2 = crs_name in dt1` and `name in dt2 = name in dt1`. i don't know what is the problem!!!

Comment: is it a whitespace or casing issue?  I've added calls to Trim and ToLower to my answer, does that fix it?

Comment: `r["crs_name"].ToString().TrimEnd() == r2["crs_name"].ToString().TrimEnd() && r["name"].ToString().TrimEnd() == r2["name"].ToString().TrimEnd()));`

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `Except` extension.

Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx) to the linq on MSDN.

From what I get from the question somthing like.

```
var theNonIntersect = 
    dt1.AsEnumerable().select(r => r.Field<string>("crs_name"), r.Field<string>("name"))
        .Except(dt2.AsEnumerable().select(r => r.Field<string>("crs_name"), r.Field<string>("name")));
```

Comment: `can't convert lambda expression to string because it's not a delegate`

Comment: try that, added the Linq to `DataTable` extensions

Comment: hmmmm .no syntax error but sorry it doesn't work. i get the same records in the first datatable .

Comment: hmmm, `r.Field<string>("name")`syntax error here . `r` doesn't exist n the current context

Answer (score 0):

HI there hope this code does help you and if i have misunderstood then can ask me to edit this post

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
var result  = from a in db.dt1
              from b in db.dt2
              where a.crs_name != b.name
              select a.crs_names;

foreach(var names in result)
{
  dt2Entity obj = new dt2Entity();
  obj.name = names.name;
  db.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
  db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: hmmm, I'm not use LINQ to sql .just wanna a LINQ answer to my question.I don't know what is `db`?and the comparsion should be among 
`a.crs_name and b.crs_name`
`a.name and b.name`