# How to find rows in tbl1 that are not in tbl2 and delete them

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a beginner with VS C# and am working on a WINFORM project I inherited.
I need to find rows in tbl1 that don't exist in tbl2 and delete them.  The joining column would be:
tbl1==> "VistaFieldName"
tbl2==> "FMFieldName"

I found some code in StackOverflow link [Get what exists in one DataTable but not another using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995085/get-what-exists-in-one-datatable-but-not-another-using-linq) that I thought might work but it's using linq and I'm not familiar with linq.

EDITED: tried the query syntax from the link and it worked but now I'm getting an exception.  If I accept changes in the first foreach loop I get 'collection modified' and if I place the accept changes outside the foreach loops I get an exception 'can't access rows marked for deletion'

What can I do to prevent this from happening?

```
else if (dsVX130.Tables["tAttributes"].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var rowsOnlyIntblsAttributes = from r in tblsAttributes.AsEnumerable() //was dt1
                        //make sure there aren't any matching names in dt2
                        where !tbltAttributes.AsEnumerable().Any(r2 => r["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == r2["FMFieldNumber"].ToString().Trim().ToLower())
                        select r;

                        DataTable result = rowsOnlyIntblsAttributes.CopyToDataTable();

                        //result.Rows[0]["VistaFieldNumber"]
                        string vresult;
                        foreach (DataRow dr in result.Rows)
                        {
                         vresult=result.Rows[0]["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString();
                            foreach (DataRow dr1 in tblsAttributes.Rows)
                            {
                                if (dr1["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString() == vresult)
                              {
                                dr1.Delete();
                                tblsAttributes.AcceptChanges();
                              }
                            }
                        }
                        tblsAttributes.AcceptChanges();
                        applyAttributes();
```

Comment: LINQ _is_ syntax that you can use in your Windows Forms application. What problem did you have when you tried this?

Comment: Any reason for choosing LINQ? Other than that it's cool to use (lol)?

Comment: John, I found one issue.  I placed a ; at the end of the first line and it didn't like that.  After removing that, each of the Trim() say Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Trim' and no extension method 'Trim' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: coe4life, it isn't like I chose it rather looking for a solution to do something I don't know how.

Comment: I added ToString() before the .Trim() and the errors cleared.  I'll see if that does it.

Comment: I get an exception that FMFieldNumber does not belong to sAttributes which is true.  Don't understand why it thinks it should.  I'm attempting to compare FMFieldNumber of tAttributes to
VistaFieldNumber of sAttributes

System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Column 'FMFieldNumber' does not belong to table sAttributes.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName)
       at System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName)
       at

Comment: Sorry I didn't include the line of code the exception is coming on.

DataTable result = rowsOnlyIntblsAttributes.CopyToDataTable();

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:  I used the query syntax example from [Get what exists in one DataTable but not another using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995085/get-what-exists-in-one-datatable-but-not-another-using-linq) to find rows in tbl1 not in tbl2 and then issued my delete row.  At first I used FOREACH but found you can't enumerate a table and delete rows at the same time.  This was resolved by replacing the FOREACH with a FOR as shown here.

In testing the final result I found I needed to test for rows returned in the query result else I received an exception when the copytable was issued.  The test I used is

```
 else if (dsVX130.Tables["tAttributes"].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var rowsOnlyIntblsAttributes = from r in tblsAttributes.AsEnumerable() //was dt1
                        //make sure there aren't any matching names in dt2
                        where !tbltAttributes.AsEnumerable().Any(r2 => r["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == r2["FMFieldNumber"].ToString().Trim().ToLower())
                        select r;

                        if (rowsOnlyIntblsAttributes.Any())
                        { 
                            DataTable result = rowsOnlyIntblsAttributes.CopyToDataTable();

                        //result.Rows[0]["VistaFieldNumber"]
                        string vresult;
                        for (int i = 0; i < result.Rows.Count; i++)

                        //foreach (DataRow dr in result.Rows)
                        {
                            //var tempRow = result.Rows[i];
                            //var temp = result.Rows[i][0];
                            vresult=result.Rows[i]["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString();
                         for (int j = 0; j < tblsAttributes.Rows.Count; j++)
                            //foreach (DataRow dr1 in tblsAttributes.Rows)
                            {
                                DataRow dr1 = tblsAttributes.Rows[j];
                                if (dr1["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString() == vresult)
                              {
                                dr1.Delete();
                                tblsAttributes.AcceptChanges();
                                break;
                              }
                                //tblsAttributes.AcceptChanges();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        //tblsAttributes.AcceptChanges();
                        applyAttributes();
```